# how to use Pivot SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, unpivot

For Example,

```
select A,B,C,D,E,YEAR
FROM t1
where t1.year = 2018
UNION ALL
select A,B,C,D,E,YEAR
FROM t2
where t2.year = 2017
```

execute like this

```
A --- B----C----D----E----YEAR
2 --- 4----6----8----10---2018
1 --- 3----5----7----9----2017
```

I would like to have a result like this

```
  2018  2017
A  2    1
B  4    3
C  6    5
D  8    7
E  10   9
```

I know I should use pivot, and googled around, but I can not figure out how to write a code to have a result like above.

Thanks

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using Oracle 11.1 or above, you can use the `pivot` and `unpivot` operators. In your problem, the data is already "pivoted" one way, but you want it pivoted the other way; so you must un-pivot first, and then re-pivot the way you want it. In the solution below, the data is read from the table (I use a WITH clause to generate the test data, but you don't need the WITH clause, you can start at SELECT and use your actual table and column names). The data is fed through `unpivot` and then immediately to `pivot` - you don't need subqueries or anything like that.

Note about column names: don't use `year`, it is an Oracle keyword and you will cause confusion if not (much) worse. And in the output, you can't have `2018` and such as column names - identifiers must begin with a letter. You can go around these limitations using names in double quotes; that is a very poor practice though, best left just to the Oracle parser and not used by us humans. You will see I called the input column `yr` and the output columns `y2018` and such.

```
with
  inputs ( a, b, c, d, e, yr ) as (
    select 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 2018 from dual union all
    select 1, 3, 5, 7,  9, 2017 from dual
  )
select   col, y2018, y2017
from     inputs
unpivot  ( val for col in (a as 'A', b as 'B', c as 'C', d as 'D', e as 'E') )
pivot    ( min(val) for yr in (2018 as y2018, 2017 as y2017) )
order by col   --   if needed
;

COL      Y2018      Y2017
--- ---------- ----------
A            2          1
B            4          3
C            6          5
D            8          7
E           10          9
```

**ADDED**:

Here is how this used to be done (before the `pivot` and `unpivot` were introduced in Oracle 11.1). Unpivoting was done with a cross join to a small helper table, with a single column and as many rows as there were columns to unpivot in the base table - in this case, five columns, `a, b, c, d, e` need to be unpivoted, so the helper table has five rows. And pivoting was done with conditional aggregation. Both can be combined into a single query - there is no need for subqueries (other than to create the helper "table" or inline view).

Note, importantly, that the base table is read just once. Other methods of unpivoting are much more inefficient, because they require reading the base table multiple times.

```
select decode(lvl, 1, 'A', 2, 'B', 3, 'C', 4, 'D', 5, 'E') as col,
       max(case yr when 2018 then decode(lvl, 1, a, 2, b, 3, c, 4, d, 5, e) end) as y2018,
       max(case yr when 2017 then decode(lvl, 1, a, 2, b, 3, c, 4, d, 5, e) end) as y2017
from   inputs cross join ( select level as lvl from dual connect by level <= 5 )
group by decode(lvl, 1, 'A', 2, 'B', 3, 'C', 4, 'D', 5, 'E')
order by decode(lvl, 1, 'A', 2, 'B', 3, 'C', 4, 'D', 5, 'E')
;
```

This looks worse than it is; the same `decode()` function is called three times, but with exactly the same arguments, so it is calculated only once, the value is cached and it is reused in the other places. (It is calculated for `group by` and then reused for `select` and for `order by`.)

To test, you can use the same WITH clause as above - or your actual data.

`decode()` is proprietary to Oracle, but the same can be written with `case` expressions (essentially identical to the `decode()` approach, just different syntax) and it will work in most other database products.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky -- unpivotting and repivotting.  Here is one way:

```
select col,
       max(case when year = 2018 then val end) as val_2018,
       max(case when year = 2017 then val end) as val_2017
from ((select 'A' as col, A as val, YEAR from t1 where year = 2018) union all
      (select 'B' as col, B as val, YEAR from t1 where year = 2018) union all
      (select 'C' as col, C as val, YEAR from t1 where year = 2018) union all
      (select 'D' as col, D as val, YEAR from t1 where year = 2018) union all
      (select 'E' as col, D as val, YEAR from t1 where year = 2018) union all
      (select 'A' as col, A as val, YEAR from t2 where year = 2017) union all
      (select 'B' as col, B as val, YEAR from t2 where year = 2017) union all
      (select 'C' as col, C as val, YEAR from t2 where year = 2017) union all
      (select 'D' as col, D as val, YEAR from t2 where year = 2017) union all
      (select 'E' as col, D as val, YEAR from t2 where year = 2017) 
     ) tt
group by col;
```

You don't specify the database, but this is pretty database independent.

Comment: Gordon: Unpivoting (if you don't want to use the `unpivot` operator) should **not** be done with UNION ALL. You should read the base table **exactly once**; cross join to a small table, with as many rows as there are columns you must unpivot.

Comment: @mathguy . . . The question was not tagged Oracle when I answered.

Comment: What does that have to do with what I said? Nothing! To unpivot, use a cross join, not multiple union all. I already showed how at the bottom of my answer.